# Deriving variance bound for estimator of $\theta$ for $X \sim \Gamma(1,\theta)$

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $X$ be a $\Gamma(1, \theta)$ random variable. Derive the variance bound for estimating $\theta$:

My attempt:

We seek a random variable $S$ s.t. $1=E_\theta(WS)$ for all estimators $W$ with $E_\theta(W)=\theta$.

So 
$$
\begin{split}
1 &= \frac{d}{d\theta}E(W)
   = \frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{\mathcal{R}^+}\frac{w}{\theta}e^{-t/\theta}dt
   = \int_{\mathcal{R}^+}\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{w}{\theta}e^{-t/\theta}dt \\
  &= \int_{\mathcal{R}^+}
         \left[w\left(\frac{t}{\theta^2}-\theta^{-1} \right) \right]
                           \theta^{-1}e^{-t/\theta}dt \\
  &= E_\theta\left[W\left(\frac{X}{\theta^2}-\theta^{-1}\right)\right]
\end{split}
$$

So $S=\frac{X}{\theta^2}-\theta^{-1}$ and the Variance bound is given by $Var_\theta S=\theta^{-4}Var_\theta X=\theta^{-2}$?

Answer (score 1):

By [Cramér–Rao_bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) in exponential family, for all unbiased estimator, $\hat{\theta}$ ,

$Var(\hat{\theta})\geq \frac{1}{\theta^2}$

Since 
in the exponential distribution ($f(x)=\frac{1}{\theta} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$)
$$I(\theta)=\theta^2$$ [Exponential_distribution#Fisher_Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Fisher_Information)

and
$Var(\hat{\theta})\geq \frac{\{1+ \frac{d}{d\theta} \left( E(\hat{\theta})-\theta \right)\}^2}{\theta^2}$